# Show image in Image Control from sql

Tags: asp.net, sql, image, controls

I have created a table name "Images".  The table structure is like this:

```
ImageID int not null
ImageName nvarchar(500) null
ImagePath nvarchar(500) null
```

I uploaded some image info in the relevant table successfully.  Now I want to show this image in different pages in the image control.  How can I accomplish this?

ASPX Page

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>
    <asp:Label ID="lblMsg" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
    <asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload1" runat="server" />`
    <br />
    <asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" runat="server" Text="Submit" 
        onclick="btnSubmit_Click" />
</div>
```

Code behind

```
protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int rst;
    string conStr = null;
    string cmdStr = null;
    string fileName = null;

    fileName = Path.GetFileName(FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName);
    FileUpload1.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("images/show/" + fileName));

    conStr = "Data Source=Server\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=Database;Integrated Security=True";
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(conStr);


    cmdStr = "Insert into Images(ImageName,ImagePath1) values (@ImageName,@ImagePath1)";
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
    cmd.CommandText = cmdStr;
    cmd.Connection = con;
    con.Open();

    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ImageName", fileName);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ImagePath1", "images/show" + fileName);
    rst = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    try
    {
        if (rst > 0)
        {
            lblMsg.Text = "Success";
        }
        else
        {
            lblMsg.Text = "Not success";
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        lblMsg.Text = ex.Message;
    }
    finally
    {
        con.Close();
    }
}
```

I want to know how to retrieve image from database anywhere i want to show it. I have not written any code for this. and i don't know how to retrieve image from database

Comment: What code have you written to retrieve the image data from your SQL table?

Comment: show us all the code that you have. your html and your asp.net code.

Comment: I have updated my post please have a look

Comment: Ok, you've shown us what code you are using to store the data.  What have you written to retrieve the data?

Comment: Garrison Neely, that is the thing i want to know how to retrieve image from database anywhere i want to show it. I have not written any code for this. and i don't know how to retrieve image from database

Comment: Any one here to solve this problem